# How can I find all elements of a numpy array which can be divided exactly by at least one element of other array?

Tags: python

For example the inputs are 2 numpy arrays: `a = np.array([3, 8, 5])` , `b = np.array([6, 11, 10, 9, 17])` the output are the elements in the array `b` which can be divided exactly by at least one element in `a`: 6, 10, 9

Comment: Did you try anything and go to problems? This is not a code-giveaway service. Please post any attempts you made and how they went wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A numpy-based solution might be the following:

```
>>> check = b[:, np.newaxis] % a == 0
>>> b[np.any(check, axis=1)]
array([ 6, 10,  9])
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming these arrays are 1D, you can do it with a simple list comprehension:

```py
[x for x in b if any([x % y == 0 for y in a])]
```